# windows phone 8.1 receive a call

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, call

I am looking for a way to do a certain function each time the phone receives a call. How can I override the usual call serviece or add functionallity to it?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do this in WP8.1.  You cannot hook into the calling system in this way.